# Wireless Debugging and USB Debugging is permanently disabled in developer options, how to enable?

Tags: android, adb, remote-debugging, usb-debugging

I am trying to enable the wireless debugging and USB debugging both are permanently disabled. On click nothing happens. My phone is Samsung F34.

I tried with switch off phone and Tethering hardware acceleration enable but still same problem.

Comment: If the phone company owned or has it an Mobile Device management (MDM) agent installed?